# Does a long Wifi Pre-Shared Key and a hidden SSID slow the network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I just have some small question. I used to put really long complicated passwords for my Wifi network. I even used to hide the SSID of the network. Does it slow down the wifi  performance? My Android devices once had problems connecting to the hidden network. So... my questions are...

1. Does hiding the SSID and adding long password slow the Wifi connection?
2. Does it give rise to other connection problems?
3. Is it the cause for frequent connection drops?

My router is DIR-615 - e4 and I faced problems with a new Galaxy Tab 2 and my new HP laptop also have problems connecting occasionally.

Comment: What authentication level are you using for your wi-fi? If it's WEP, the length of the password is irrelevant because you may as well not bother. On WPA and WPA2, the password length *shouldn't* affect network speed.

Comment: Short answers: no, no, no.

Comment: @RandolphWest I use WPA2

Comment: @RandolphWest Will it cause problems if i set it to WPA2 Only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No.
2. It has no benefit, so just don't do it. But it can make it harder for clients to find the access point and it can make it impossible for clients to pick the best access point (if you have more than one).
3. That's possible if the access point isn't locked on one frequency and is set to choose a frequency automatically. It's not that likely if the AP is set to one channel.

Answer (score 3):

> Does hiding the SSID ...

Hiding the SSID does have a impact on the functionality of your network, and it also doesn't really hide your network.  Disabling SSID beaconing makes it harder for clients to find your AP.  There is no value in hiding your SSID.

Ref:

- http://www.library.cornell.edu/dlit/ds/links/cit/redrover/ssid/wp_ssid_hiding.pdf
- http://www.zdnet.com/blog/ou/the-six-dumbest-ways-to-secure-a-wireless-lan/43

> long password slow the Wifi connection?

Long passwords shouldn't affect speed or availability.

Answer (score 2):

No, the length of the SSID or pre-shared-key has no bearing on performance.  These are used only at the initiation of a session in any case.

Hiding the SSID has no effect on performance either, and does not enhance security in a meaningful way.  Any scanner can detect hidden networks.

Neither of these things can cause connection drops.

While this does answer your question, it appears that you have an underlying connection issue that needs resolving.  It is far better to frame your question without introducing your hunches as to the cause (known as [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).  The question should include the devices involved, configuration details, and the behaviour you are witnessing and whether there is a pattern to the behaviour.

Comment: Added the involved devices

Comment: Hiding the SSID can and does affect your connection if your connection is week and the client decides it needs to attempt to roam to another AP.

Answer (score 2):

No, because your password is used to generate a key which will be of a fixed length regardless of your password length.  The encryption algorithm and access points processor determines the speed, which you generally have little control over.

However for 99.9% of users the lag created by encryption is not noticeable.

More likely connection issues are related to Wifi signal noise, which can come from overlapping channels from other routers or mirrored signals from your own walls.